# Javascript - how to directly interact with db?

Tags: javascript

I have an excel sheet, a JS application and a db. excel sheet has data. I need to open the file and read data from the JS application and insert it into the db(say oracle db). How to?

I think we cannot open and close file in JS, pls correct me if i am wrong since it poses a security issue. If that is the case, say if we have updated the data in the grid, or table in the JS application. and we want to insert all the data in to the db, how do we do it?

Comment: Depends on in which environment the application is running and what the capabilities of the DB are.

Comment: JavaScript run on a browser which has a very strict security restrictions. And keeping any connection string on JavaScript is not a good practice at all . Don't keep any sensitive things on client side. Make a call to server side validate and work on that.

Answer (score 1):

First- there is pretty good module to read/write excel files in javascript-client or javascript-server:

[js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

Someone has used it and provided a blog on its usage [here](http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/)

Second- You have to involve one more tier (server) to get the work done as per security standards. Or another option is BaaS (Back-end-as-Service) like Parse, Firebase to serve your client as database, it lets you directly save your stuff without involving/writing server. Or other option is to use SaaS like Mongolab, it exposes api for client to directly save into db.

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this safely. You need a webservice that the javascript app can call and that service would write to the database. So you should build a restful web api.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Proxy Service for interacting to DB. There is no db-connectors for JS. The simplest way to achieve your goal is to choose one of the scripting languages which can run on your server. Such as PHP, Python, ASP.NET, ASP etc. I suggest PHP or Python.